# Regex pattern for "contains not only spaces"

Tags: java, regex

Please tell me which pattern I need to use if field must not contain only spaces.

Comment: "\s+" means "one or more whitespaces of any kind".

Comment: Case is so important.  Corrected.

Comment: nobody understand my question..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why need to use regex?

```
str.trim().isEmpty()
```

Comment: this generates a copy of a string object, not sure it outperforms regex

Answer (score 15):

You must use this pattern.

```
.*[^ ].*
```

It can be anything but not only spaces.

Comment: In javascript this regex does not allow any spaces at all

Comment: you may need to add a `/ /g` flag, but this is the simplest answer

Answer (score 2):

assuming you mean any whitespace, not just spaces, `\S` will work.

Cfr every dev's must-have friend, [The regex cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: field could be "Hi i am" but could not be "    ". It can contain spaces but not only spaces

Comment: @KirillBazarov: If your string matches \S it means that it has at least one character that is not a whitespace. It still can contain whitespaces.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth indeed.  I think that's what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2):

I've got one, it seems heavy, but it's not that hard to implement.

Pattern with no blank:

```
^[pattern]\*[pattern without space][pattern]*$
```

Example:

```
-pattern: a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ '\-
```

(note that it allows spaces)

```
[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ '\-]
```

With no blank =

```
^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ '\-]\*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ'\-][a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ '\-]*
```

Of course, if you don't allow spaces at all, you don't need to do that.

You can test yours on https://regexr.com/.

Answer (score 0):

This is much simple .If you are using java just code this.
As example:-

classVariable.getname().trim().equal("")

by this you can check whether that variable contains only spaces.