# To prevent only spaces in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular, whitespace

How do I prevent only spaces in the text area? I don't want to allow only white spaces in the text area using HTML pattern or `Validator.pattern`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568451/regex-pattern-for-contains-not-only-spaces, the pattern `.*[^ ].*`

Comment: added the $.trim() method

Comment: thanks @Eliseo that pattern worked

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex for no spaces:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[^' ']+" />
</form>
```

Comment: It blocks all the spaces btween the text. I want to restrict only spaces not spaces between text